# Character for "□" 西南官话 kuai³¹: "～着走, 两脚尖向内地走"

Tags: characters, character-identification

`□` is the official place-marker for unknown or unwritable characters. Sometimes though there are appropriate characters for the mistakenly believed unwritable or nonexistent.

Here's my conundrum:

《现代汉语方言音库》

《成都话音档》

> □
>
> kuai³¹
>
> ～着走, 两脚尖向内地走

《成都方言词典》

> [image: 2]

《四川方言词典》

> [image: 3]

I'm willing to bet the missing character could be written *拐*, but I haven't any proof.

What character could be written here instead of □?

Comment: I believe it's 拐 too. In some dialects it's pronounced as `kuai`. Maybe you can email the editor of the dictionary to confirm your speculation.

Comment: This character's pronunciation always reminds of "quack", which comes from both the imitation of the walking posture and the onomatopoeia of the sound of of a duck.

Answer (score 2):

There could be two answers to this question.

1.拐 can pronounced as kuai in some dialects. For example, in Lufeng dialect, it's pronounced as kuai3.

2.擓(pronounced as kuai3 in Mandarin, Unicode:U+64D3).

This character has three meanings:

First, in some dialects it means scratch, such as ShanDong dialect and Mandarin of Jianghuai.

Second, in others dialects it means carrying on arm, it's used as a synonym for 挎(kua2). In this sense, it can be interpreted as an adjective. To describe the posture that deliberately lift legs in walking.

Third, it means ladle out.

When we use the second meaning, it could be written in the common sayings(一～一～).

Sorry for my terrible English. Hope my answer is helpful.

Comment: K above is IPA a mandarin pinyin equivalent of kuai would be guai. So your post kind of missed the point completely.

Comment: I got a copy of 《成都方言詞典》 from my university library(ISBN: 7-5343-3420-9, you can get same version in Baidu). In the part of 分地方言詞典總序, it says, 詞典正文按字音排列，以本方言的韻母、聲母、聲調爲序, Which means this dictionary mark pronunciation with Mandarin pinyin(not IPA). @user3306356